# How did they get these partial derivatives?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, change-of-variable

[image]

How did they go from the first set of partials to the second set of partials? In other words, how did they factor out $\frac{df}{dx}$ and $\frac{df}{dy}$ ?

Comment: What did you try? Solve the system.

Comment: You're solving for the Cartesian derivatives in terms of the polar ones. Begin by, say, multiplying by $r$ in the first equation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first two equations are a system of equations $Au = v$, where $A = \begin{bmatrix} \cos \theta & \sin \theta  \\ -r \sin \theta & r \cos \theta \end{bmatrix}$, $ u = \begin{bmatrix} \frac{\partial f}{\partial r} \\ \frac{\partial f}{\partial \theta}\end{bmatrix} $, $ v = \begin{bmatrix} \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \\ \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\end{bmatrix} $, and so the bottom equations are simply $ u = A^{-1}v$.

Comment: Wow, excellent! Thank you so much :)

Comment: i think the 'u' and 'v' are switched up, but other than that, perfect! :D